# Get unauthorized in adding boarding pass to google pay

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-pay

I want to create a boarding pass with google pay API. I followed up [Get access to REST API steps](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api) and then for making flight class request(based this [link](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/boarding-passes/code-snippets)), I use Google.Apis.Auth in .net. I get Unauthorized after post request.

This is my code:

```
 var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"~\Certificate\AbomisWallet-4bca1ef0e957.json");
 credential = credential.CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer");

 var serviceC = credential.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

 JToken myJtoken;

 using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"~\Temp\myJson.json"))
 {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        myJtoken = JToken.FromObject(json);
 }

var content = new StringContent(myJtoken.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        serviceC.HttpClient.BaseAddress =  new Uri("https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/flightClass");

var result = serviceC.HttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri ("https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/flightClass")
            , content).Result;
```

And this is my error:

```
{ "error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Login Required.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "location": "Authorization",
    "locationType": "header"
  }
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" }}
```

Comment: Can you show us where the error is, and give us the entire error message? Thanks!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I edit my question.

Comment: Ok! Well, the error is pretty clear. `Request is missing required authentication credential`. I can't take the time to read all their docs and figure out why/how you are not properly authenticating. But I'm sure this same issue has been asked an ansewred before. Do some google work. Also, there is a nuget package for working with Google API's that could make this easier: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: Please see library and sample for doing this to abstract away token work. https://github.com/angelbarranco/passes-rest-samples/tree/master/csharp

Answer (score 0):

This is insane, but you need to get and set the token manualy.

change your code like this

```
 var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"~\Certificate\AbomisWallet-4bca1ef0e957.json");
            credential = credential.CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer");

            var serviceC = credential.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

            JToken myJtoken;

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"~\Temp\myJson.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                myJtoken = JToken.FromObject(json);
            }

            var content = new StringContent(myJtoken.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var token = await serviceC.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            serviceC.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            serviceC.HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/flightClass");

            var result = serviceC.HttpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("https://walletobjects.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/flightClass")
                        , content).Result;
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please see library and sample for doing this to abstract away token work. https://github.com/angelbarranco/passes-rest-samples/tree/master/csharp